# How to add a Custom Annotation on Java Files

Tags: java, annotations, code-generation

I have Java files which are created using Reverse Engineering for Database to create JPA entities. I have these file paths and would like to add `@MyCustomAnnotation(value="something")` annotation to these Java Files. I want this to be a part of my build process, hence I would integrate the same in Maven. However, I could not find a way to do so to existing Java Files.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Can you clarify the question a little bit? Do you need help with creating a custom annotation or integrating that custom annotation into maven? or both?

Comment: I created the Custom Annotation. I need to maybe create a Maven Plugin which adds the Custom Annotation on Class file like an class enhancer.